# white listing solution against fortify erros does not remove the fortify errors

Tags: fortify

when i ran fority scanner it reported often misused authentication issue on the below line

> > hostName=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

I had written a function which will validate this host name against the white list of host names as below.

```
private String validateHost(String hostName)
        {
            String[] PossibleHosts = {"host1","host2","host2","host4","host5",};
            Integer myhostIndex = Arrays.asList(PossibleHosts).indexOf((hostName).toLowerCase());
            if(myhostIndex>=0){
                hostName = PossibleHosts[myhostIndex];
            } else {
                hostName = "";
            }
            return hostName;
        }
```

which will be called by below line

> hostName=validateHost(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());

But when i run the fority scan for the next time , it still shows issue on the same line even after i have done the validaiton. what can be done to remove the fortify error.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you, let me explain how Fortify detects this issue, why it's included, then what to do about it.

How Fortify detects this issue: It's basically a super grep. It just finds anywhere you're using java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() and complains. It is unaffected by data validation.

Why do this? Because this function is sometimes used for security purposes, and it should not be. For example, imagine a dev wanted to trust all messages from their own domain, they might use this to determine where a message came from. But then the security of their system relies on DNS, which is not secure. (See the Details tab for more info.)

What to do: First, make sure that what you're trying to do with java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() is safe. Basically, that you're not trying to secure your system with this code. Then ignore the finding. At most companies I help, you would write a short explanation of why this code is OK, put it in the comment field of the Issue Summary tab, and mark the Analysis as "Not an Issue." At some places, you could also suppress it. If you're getting a ton of these, you can create a Filter that will knock out the whole category, but realize that you might also knock out some real issues that way.

Source of information: Consultant at Fortify Software 2008-2010, independent application security consultant since then.

Comment: This is just and info which is used to  log the host. I am not doing any operation based on its output. But still i wanted to remove the fortify errors some how and clean my result. Is there any possible way for it?

Comment: There's no change to the code that will remove the issue. You can cause Fortify to not display it by suppressing or filtering it.